# Google Analytics Tracker Not working for android app

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I have included Google analytics in my app.
But when i create an object of `Tracker` the tracker does not work

Code in one of my activity

```
    @Override
protected void onStart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart();
    try{
        tracker=((GoogleAnalyticsConfig)this.getApplication()).getTracker(GoogleAnalyticsConfig.TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
        tracker.setScreenName("HomeActivity");
        tracker.send(new HitBuilders.AppViewBuilder().build());
    }catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Now with this code i don't see the app in Realtime tracking
but if i change the above code with this

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart();
    try{
        GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
        analytics.reportActivityStart(this);
    }catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I can see that one user is active in Realtime

Code for `GoogleAnalyticsConfig`

```
  public enum TrackerName {
    APP_TRACKER, // Tracker used only in this app.
    GLOBAL_TRACKER, // Tracker used by all the apps from a company. eg: roll-up tracking.
  }

  HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker> mTrackers = new HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker>();
// The following line should be changed to include the correct property id.
private static final String PROPERTY_ID ="UA-XXXXXXXX-1";

public synchronized Tracker getTracker(TrackerName trackerId) {
    if (!mTrackers.containsKey(trackerId)) {

      GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
      Tracker t = analytics.newTracker(PROPERTY_ID);
      t.enableAutoActivityTracking(true);

      mTrackers.put(trackerId, t);

    }
    return mTrackers.get(trackerId);
  }
```

Can any one tell me why tracker is not working?Also not only realtime but also in all the screens where i have included the tracker its not showing in App Overview section of Google Analytics ,even after 48 hrs.

Comment: can you put your code in oncreate and have you put app_tracker.xml and other two xml file in res->xml folder?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

in res folder create xml folder with below three xml file

app_tracker.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<!-- Replace placeholder ID with your tracking ID -->
<string name="ga_trackingId">XX-XXXXXXXX-X</string>

<bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>
<bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>

<string name="ga_appName">Serivce</string>
<string name="ga_appVersion">1.1.3</string>

<bool name="ga_debug">true</bool>

<item name="ga_dispatchPeriod" format="integer" type="integer">120</item>

<string name="ga_sampleFrequency">90</string>

<bool name="ga_anonymizeIp">true</bool>
<bool name="ga_dryRun">false</bool>

<!-- Percentage of events to include in reports -->
<string name="ga_sampleFrequency">100.0</string>

<!-- How long a session exists before giving up -->
<integer name="ga_sessionTimeout">-1</integer>

<string name="com.example.ui.MainActivity">MainActivity</string>
```

ecommerce_tracker.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
 <integer name="ga_sessionTimeout">60</integer>
 <!--  The following value should be replaced with correct property id. -->
 <string name="ga_trackingId">XX-XXXXXXX-1</string>
</resources>
```

global_tracker.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<!-- The following value should be replaced with correct property id. -->
<string name="ga_trackingId">XX-XXXXXXX-1</string>

<integer name="ga_sessionTimeout">300</integer>

<bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>

<!-- the Local LogLevel for Analytics -->
<string name="ga_logLevel">verbose</string>

<!-- how often the dispatcher should fire -->
<integer name="ga_dispatchPeriod">30</integer>

<!-- Treat events as test events and don't send to google -->
<bool name="ga_dryRun">false</bool>

<screenName name="com.example.ui.MainActivity">MainActivity</screenName>
```

create java file with 
AnalyticsSampleApp.java and register this file in menifest like in application tag with android:name="com.example.ui.AnalyticsSampleApp"

```
public class AnalyticsSampleApp extends Application {

// The following line should be changed to include the correct property id.
private static final String PROPERTY_ID = "XX-XXXXXX-1";

public static int GENERAL_TRACKER = 0;
public enum TrackerName {
    APP_TRACKER, // Tracker used only in this app.
    GLOBAL_TRACKER, // Tracker used by all the apps from a company. eg: roll-up tracking.
    ECOMMERCE_TRACKER, // Tracker used by all ecommerce transactions from a company.
}

public HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker> mTrackers = new HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker>();

public AnalyticsSampleApp() {
    super();
}

public synchronized Tracker getTracker(TrackerName trackerId) {
    if (!mTrackers.containsKey(trackerId)) {
        GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
        Tracker t = (trackerId == TrackerName.APP_TRACKER) ? analytics.newTracker(PROPERTY_ID): (trackerId == TrackerName.GLOBAL_TRACKER) ? analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker): analytics.newTracker(R.xml.ecommerce_tracker);
        mTrackers.put(trackerId, t);

    }
    return mTrackers.get(trackerId);
  }
}
```

in MainActivity onCreate put below

```
    Tracker t = ((AnalyticsSampleApp)this.getApplication()).getTracker(TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
    t.setScreenName(TAG);
    t.send(new HitBuilders.AppViewBuilder().build());
```

Comment: I'll try this and let you know

Comment: tell u the truth ,it jst started working.Although i wrote
`tracker.set("HomeActivity","Home");` in most of my screen which i replaced with `tracker.setScreenName("HomeActivity");` and the tracker for other screens started working.But it should have worked with above `onStart()`.Don't know why even that didn't work

Comment: What's the difference between a Tracking Id and Property Id ?

Comment: @PankajAndroid ga_trackingId  and PROPERTY_ID are same means tracking id that we got from google Analytics a/c. I have follow all the steps https://samsulhoquesolution.wordpress.com/2014/09/23/how-to-use-google-analytics-api-v4-in-android-apps/ given by this post. Still tracking is not showing in google Analytics a/c

Comment: this is almost copy-pasted from https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/advanced

Comment: if you forget to add the application to android manifest you will get an error talking about cannot be cast...