# Google Analytics Campaign Tracking: Testing

Tags: java, android, google-analytics

I am trying to implement google analytics campaign tracking into my app. The relevant code is:

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.prakhar.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle; import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton; import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar; import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar; import android.util.Log; import android.view.Menu; import android.view.MenuItem; import android.view.View;

import com.google.android.gms.analytics.HitBuilders; import com.google.android.gms.analytics.Tracker;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        Tracker t = ((AnalyticsApplication) getApplication()).getTracker(AnalyticsApplication.TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
        String campaignData = "http://examplepetstore.com/index.html?" +
                "utm_source=email&utm_medium=email_marketing&utm_campaign=summer" +
                "&utm_content=email_variation_1";

        Log.d("MainActivity", "Sending an event");
        t.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder()
                        .setCampaignParamsFromUrl(campaignData)
                        .build()
        );
        Log.d("MainActivity", "Event sent");

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    } }
```

AnalyticsApplication.java

```
package com.example.prakhar.myapplication;

import android.app.Application;

import com.google.android.gms.analytics.GoogleAnalytics;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.Tracker;

import java.util.HashMap;

/**
 * Created by prakhar on 2/12/15.
 */
public class AnalyticsApplication extends Application{
    private Tracker mTracker;

    // The following line should be changed to include the correct property id.
    private static final String PROPERTY_ID = "UA-XXXX-XX";

    /**
     * Enum used to identify the tracker that needs to be used for tracking.
     *
     * A single tracker is usually enough for most purposes. In case you do need multiple trackers,
     * storing them all in Application object helps ensure that they are created only once per
     * application instance.
     */
    public enum TrackerName {
        APP_TRACKER,
        GLOBAL_TRACKER,
    }

    HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker> mTrackers = new HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker>();

    synchronized Tracker getTracker(TrackerName trackerId) {
        if (!mTrackers.containsKey(trackerId)) {

            GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
            Tracker t = (trackerId == TrackerName.APP_TRACKER) ? analytics.newTracker(PROPERTY_ID)
                    : analytics.newTracker(R.xml.app_tracker);
            mTrackers.put(trackerId, t);

        }
        return mTrackers.get(trackerId);
    }

    synchronized public Tracker getDefaultTracker()
    {
        if (mTracker == null)
        {
            GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
            mTracker = analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker);
        }
        return mTracker;
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.prakhar.myapplication" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:name="com.example.prakhar.myapplication.AnalyticsApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Used for Google Play Store Campaign Measurement-->

        <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsReceiver"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.ANALYTICS_DISPATCH" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"/>

        <!-- Optionally, register CampaignTrackingReceiver and CampaignTrackingService to enable
             installation campaign reporting -->
        <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

app_tracker.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <integer name="ga_sessionTimeout">300</integer>
    <bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>
    <string name="ga_trackingId">UA-XXXXXX </string>
    <string name="ga_sampleFrequency">100.0</string>
    <bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>
</resources>
```

Essentially, I should get a log as soon as I install the app, but that is not happening. Where am I going wrong? Am I testing it the wrong way?

Initially I was getting the `ClassCastException` but that I resolved by including the name in the android manifest.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, but on web pages, when you install analytics you have to wait more or less 1/2 days to begin to work.

Comment: I installed it yesterday on the app, and I've been working since 9 in the morning and currently its 4, that's not enough?

Comment: I really don't know, wait until tomorrow.

Comment: I was looking this, you haven't app_traker.xml right? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25658269/google-analytics-tracker-not-working-for-android-app

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that. There you go.